# Ionic 2 Toggle save data with Storage

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a very simple question , i am building an app where i have a settings page with a toggle input for a user to turn on and off some alerts . My question is how do i save the toggle value so as when someone closes the app or navigate to another page the toggle status should not get lost and the current toggle should be reflected in html. At the moment i am using cordova-sqlite-storage plugin to store the toggle value .

Page.html

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>300 Units</ion-label>
    <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="AlertOn200"  [checked]="toggleStatus" (ionChange)="Change_Toggle_on_200();"></ion-toggle>
  </ion-item>
```

Page.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-page2',
  templateUrl: 'page2.html'
})
export class Page2 {
  AlertOn200:any;
  toggleStatus:any;
  val:any;  
  constructor(public storage: Storage) {      
     storage.ready().then(() => {
     // get a key/value pair
      storage.get('toggleStatus').then((val) => {
      this.val=val;
      console.log('Status = ', val);
       })
     });  
  }  
  Change_Toggle_on_200() {
  if(this.AlertOn200== true){
      this.storage.set('toggleStatus','true');         
       console.log("isAlertOn200 = "+this.toggleStatus);   
   }
   else{
   this.storage.set('toggleStatus','false');
   console.log("isAlertOn200 = "+this.toggleStatus);
    }
  }
```

Comment: so.. the issue is?

Comment: The code does not work , the togglestatus value is not saved  when i navigate to another page and come back . please read my question again .

Comment: is `storage` a custom provider that accesses the plugin?

Comment: i have updated the page.ts , the storage is from  cordova-sqlite-storage plugin .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `storage.ready()` you should set the `AlertOn200` and/or `toggleStatus` property in your class instead of the `val` property. This should set the toggle to the value in your storage.

EDIT: I've added some code below which I've tested and works.
The ion-toggle gets its initial value set by the value in the storage, if you manually toggle the ion-toggle, the value in storage changes.

I would suggest removing the `[checked]` binding in the ion-toggle component and set the model of the toggle to `toggleStatus`, like so:

```
<ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="toggleStatus" (ionChange)="Change_Toggle_on_200();"></ion-toggle>
```

If you then implement the following class:

```
export class Page1 {
  toggleStatus: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public storage: Storage) {
    storage.ready().then(() => {
      storage.get('toggleStatus').then((val) => {
        console.log(`Setting status from storage to '${this.toggleStatus}'`);
        this.toggleStatus = val; // <-- Just set this.toggleStatus to the value from storage, this will make the ion-toggle change value from default to value from storage
      })
    });
  }

  Change_Toggle_on_200() {
    console.log(`changing toggleStatus to '${this.toggleStatus}'`);
    this.storage.set('toggleStatus', this.toggleStatus); // <-- note we can just set the current value of this.toggleStatus as this changes with the toggle
  }
}
```

Comment: lemme ask , can you process the toggle event on  storage.ready() instead of doing it inside the function . sorry , its still unclear to me...can you please explain with codes :-)

Comment: I will try to respond in ~20 minutes with some code

Comment: Thanks a lot it works :-) so , if you have ngModel , there is no need to use [checked] ?

Comment: Processing the change event of the ion-toggle component in the `storage.ready()` function is not possible, this will have to go through `(ionChange)="Change_Toggle_on_200();"`

Getting the initial value from storage, however, is possible in the `storage.ready()` function.  

I think the `[(ngModel)]` handles the checked by itself.